# How are spacer sequences created in a prokaryotic genome?

Tags: bacteriology, virology, crispr, cas9

The CRISPR/Cas defense mechanism uses spacer sequences between palindromic repeats to search for the sequence to cut by an endonuclease. But how are these spacers created?

Let's take Bacteriophages, for example, which insert and integrate their genome into the prokaryotic genome. How does this infected cell get rid of the viral genome so that only a piece of the virus remains between palindromic repeats?

Comment: https://academic.oup.com/nar/article/50/3/1661/6511979